# Unexpected sh syntax error while using popen

Tags: c, linux, openssl, popen, printf

I have written a C code as given below for decrypting an encrypted string, using `popen` for the purpose.

```
snprintf(cmdcheck,1000,"echo %s %c openssl aes-256-cbc -d -a -salt -pass pass:excel2012", idcheck,'|');
FILE *cmdid = popen(cmdcheck,"r");
```

The code complies well, but on running gives the following error:

```
sh: Syntax error: "|" unexpected
```

What can be done to resolve the issue?  Thanks in advance.  My operating platform is Linux.

Comment: What is the value of `idcheck`?

Comment: I would also like to add that you could try to debug this by printing our `cmdid` to see what `sh` is seeing.

Comment: The value of idcheck is U2FsdGVkX19E6/iCgjSagVvLvLzNdKylX0SgifrSQa4=

Answer (score 0):

the clue is that the error is coming out of sh - "|" is a reserved character in sh so you need to escape it: '\|' should do it.